# VHDL - Draw the structure of the code [Help]

Tags: vhdl

I'm up doing some exercises in VHDL right now and I need some help from you guys, some guidance to push me into the right path.

The code is the following:

```
signal clk,reset:std_logic
signal q:unsigned(3 downto 0);

process(clk,reset)
   variable count:integer range 0 to 15;
begin
   if (reset=’1’) then
      q<=(others=>’0’);
      count :=0;
   elsif (clk’event and clk=’1’) then
      count:=conv_integer(q);
      count:=count+1 mod 16;
      q<=conv_unsigned(count,4);
  end if;
end process;
```

The first part where you output the "q" can be skipped, I'm just interested in the "count" part.
I will also add two pictures illustrating how I believe it can be done.
OBS! Please keep in mind that the count is a variable inside a process, incase you miss that.

Damn I can't upload an image, need 10 rep points. Can I post it with an external link to ImagesHack?

Cheers

Comment: Damn that's some ugly code...  is there a reason that you can't just do: q <= q + 1?  Because that's exactly what your code is doing...  Regardless, look up a Full Adder: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29

Comment: As @Russell said, this is a very complicated way of doing q <= q+1. Another suggestion is to use rising_edge(clk) instead of (clk’event and clk=’1’)

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the fast responses.
My bad for not making it clear for you, the task is not to find a more simple way of writing it, it's to draw a structure of the written code.
Once again, my bad for not making it clear.

Cheers PS. Can I add an external link with a picture ?

Comment: Did you look at the full adder link that I posted?  That's what it will look like.

Comment: The structure of the code? Do you mean RTL diagram?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. The adder can be drawn as shown in the wikipedia link by @Russell , but I don't think that is the point of this exercise. Both, the signal `q` and the variable `count` will infer a register.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Hello, the reason why I didn't take a look at the adder in wiki is due to that you shall draw the structure (or rather said RTL, as @Wisatbff mentioned) exactly as the code is written, not a simplified one. Also the count is a variable and not a signal, shouldn't it change the way how " count := count + 1 " is wired? A friend of mine is saying that the " + 1 " should be after the clock.

Comment: What I drew is RTL. What do you mean by " + 1 should be after the clock"? What is "after the clock" ?

Comment: My bad for not explaining well enough, As a newbie with VHDL it's not that simple. Let me make it clear.
When Rising edge occurs 1. Count := Q => a wire from Q should be directed to count. Is this wire connected before the input to the plus operator? 2. Count := Count + 1 => Because Count is a variable and not a signal the + operator should occur after the first flip-flop. Cheers